# How to reshape X_train and y_train for LSTM keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have the following:

```
X_train.shape
(2730, 10)

y_train.shape
(2730)
```

I want to train LSTM model with keras, but I'm not sure how to reshape the input.

I have added this LSTM layer

```
time_steps = 30
input_dim = 10 # number of features
...
self.model.add(LSTM(self.hidden_dim, input_shape=(time_steps, self.input_dim), return_sequences=True))
...
```

The input_shape doesn't match my input. How should I reshape my X_train? Do I also have to reshape the y_train?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I reshape my X_train?

The simplest option would be to add a `timesteps` dimension to your data to make it compatible with an `LSTM`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

samples = 5
features = 10
data = tf.random.normal((samples, features))
time_series_data = tf.expand_dims(data, axis=1) # add timesteps dimension
tf.print('Data -->', tf.shape(data), 'Time series data', tf.shape(time_series_data))
# Data --> [5 10] Time series data [5 1 10]
```

However, you want to use 30 `timesteps` for each feature leading to the shape `(samples, 30, 10)`. So, what you can use is the [RepeatVector](https://keras.io/api/layers/reshaping_layers/repeat_vector/) layer as part of your model or [tf.repeat](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/repeat). Here is an example with the `RepeatVector` layer:

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, input_shape=(features,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(30))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.build((1, 10))
tf.print(model.summary())
```

```
Model: "sequential_01"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense_24 (Dense)            (None, 10)                110       
                                                                 
 repeat_vector_1 (RepeatVect  (None, 30, 10)           0         
 or)                                                             
                                                                 
 lstm_3 (LSTM)               (None, 32)                5504      
                                                                 
 dense_25 (Dense)            (None, 1)                 33        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 5,647
Trainable params: 5,647
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

You could also first map the 10 features to a 300-dimensional output and then reshape the output to fit into an `LSTM`:

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(300, input_shape=(features,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((30, 10)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

```
Model: "sequential_02"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense_26 (Dense)            (None, 300)               3300      
                                                                 
 reshape (Reshape)           (None, 30, 10)            0         
                                                                 
 lstm_4 (LSTM)               (None, 32)                5504      
                                                                 
 dense_27 (Dense)            (None, 1)                 33        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 8,837
Trainable params: 8,837
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

To the question:

> Do I also have to reshape the y_train?

It depends on what you want. If you only have a simple classification task, as I have assumed in the examples, then you do not need to change y_train.

***Update 1:***
You can also reshape your data like the following. Resulting in the tensor with 91 samples where each sample has 30 timesteps and each timestep is associated with 10 features.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

timesteps = 2730
features = 10
data = tf.random.normal((timesteps, features))
data = tf.reshape(data, (91, 30, features))
print(data.shape)
# (91, 30, 10)
```

Comment: Does the 32 units you entered for model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32)) have a specific meaning or could be arbitrary replaced?

Comment: No specific meaning, just the output space of the LSTM. Define it how you want.

Comment: Thanks. Just one thing isn't clear about RepeatVector() . If it just "repeats" the input n times, how does it capture the sequential nature of the time series? Am I missing something? I thought the timesteps (30) shouldn't be just a repetition of the input 30 times, but 30 actual steps in the time series.

Comment: Yes, you are right! But the thing is, your data, the way it is, does not have a sequential nature. That is why I made the suggestions that I did. Although I would recommend using the first option.

Comment: The data I'm using it's actually a time series

Comment: How so ? Can you elaborate? :)

Comment: It's a time series with 2730 steps and each step has 10 features. I'm predicting the value associated to each time step.

Comment: I am sorry, I Didn't see that this discussion is still ongoing here.I think that all  2730 is one big time serie.

Comment: And you have to reshape  the labels too , y_train =  tf.reshape(y_train , (-1 , 30))